# Hippo CMS creation date of folder

Tags: date, directory, jcr, hippocms

I have been trying to get the creation date of a folder on hippo cms. So far I have been incapable of doing so. Using the debugger I get some properties:

[image]

I have also taken a look at the cms console to see if there is a date related property:

[image]

My question is if such property even exists or the cms can be configured to store this date each time a folder is created.
Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This property does not exist. To add this you would have to create a custom property on the folder type and add a custom workflow to set it. Note that you cannot simply add the mixin hippostdpubwf:document. This would add the relevant properties, but the folder workflow does not support it, and it also adds properties that are not relevant to a folder.

For help on creating workflows see:
https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/workflow/workflow.html

Answer (score 0):

For documents, the hippostdpubwf:creationDate is set to now, as defined in a mapping at /hippo:configuration/hippo:queries/hippo:templates/new-document/hippostd:modify.

Perhaps if you do similar for the new-folder is works with only configuration.

Regards, 
Jeroen

Comment: No that won't work. The property is set by workflow, you would need to customize that.